# How do I got Multiple Selections in UICollection View using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm new to swift and building iOS Application from the scratch (using swift 4) and want to do something like below.
1. Implement Multiple cell selections in UICollectionView,
2. Pass selected cells data to Server.
Please anyone can help me, how to do that? Tell me the process and supporting articles to do that.

Below is reference Image. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Reference Image/Screen]

Comment: Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701820/how-to-achieve-multiple-selections-in-uicollection-view-using-swift-4) was closed as it was too broad, this is basically a duplicate. We can not do your project for you and we cannot search the internet for articles for you. Multiple selection in a UICollectionView has been answered on this site many times, so please do some research. Post specific problems, explain the issue and post your code and we will try to help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This basic example. You can change as per your data.

When you select any cell then you need to check that selected cell is already selected before or not.

If not then add selected cell `indexPath` in `indexArray` and selected cell value in `valueArray`.

If current selected cell is previously selected then remove `indexPath` from `indexArray` and also remove selected cell value from `valueArray`

on `continue` button press pass `arrSelectedData` to server or next screen.

Define below 3 array.

```
var arrData = [String]() // This is your data array
var arrSelectedIndex = [IndexPath]() // This is selected cell Index array
var arrSelectedData = [String]() // This is selected cell data array
```

//UICollectionView Delegate & DataSource

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout 
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) { // You need to check wether selected index array contain current index if yes then change the color
            cell.vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            cell.vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }

        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

        let strData = arrData[indexPath.item]

        if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {
            arrSelectedIndex = arrSelectedIndex.filter { $0 != indexPath}
            arrSelectedData = arrSelectedData.filter { $0 != strData}
        }
        else {
            arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath)
            arrSelectedData.append(strData)
        }

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's old...but I need to point something, is not good to check if cell is selected in `cellForItemAt`, instead preselect for example in `viewDidLoad` and use `selectItem(at:::)`, also with this approach no need for unnecessary layoutSubviews and reloadData.

Answer (score 37):

Well, the best way to handle multiple selections in UICollectionView

1. Enable Multiple Selection

```swift
myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

2. put this code in your cell `awakeFromNib`

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
        
  let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
  self.backgroundView = view
        
  let coloredView = UIView(frame: bounds)
  coloredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  self.selectedBackgroundView = coloredView
}
```

3. you can get the selected `indexPath` items

```swift
let items = myCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
```

Answer (score 9):

You can write the code like this to Enable Multiple Selection :-

```
yourCollectionViewName.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

then you can Do it like this to see the cell Selected -

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if cell?.selected == true {
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
}
```

To Deselect You can do something Like this -

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
   var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Enable Multiple Selection

```
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

- Overrider *isSelected* property of collectionViewCell.

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                //You can change this method according to your need.
                setSelected()
            }
            else {
                //You can change this method according to your need.
                setUnselected()
            }
        }
    }

    func setSelected(){
        bgView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        bgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.Palette.darkBlue.cgColor
        bgView.backgroundColor = .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }
    
    func setUnselected(){
        bgView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        bgView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
```

- You can print selected cell's indexPath

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to achieve a thing like that, you need to mainly perform the following tasks

1. Whenever user clicks on a particular cell, you need to change the background colour for that *item* in the `didSelectItemAt` delegate method of `UICollectionView`
2. Now to send that data to *server*, you need an `array` to store all the selected cells and then send that array to server . You can perform the same in `didSelectItemAt` method as well

I can show you a prototype of what the function will look like:

Let's assume you have an array named `arrayForPopulating` for populating data inside `Collection View` and we have array named `finalSelections` which consist of names of all the selections that user made

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

   // Change the background colour of the cell here
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

   // Add the selected cell's data to the array
   finalSelections.append(arrayForPopulating[indexPath.row])

}
```

Now you can send you `finalSelections` array to the server !

Comment: How to remove the selected cell from array[finalSelections], if user deselects the selected cell.

Comment: Fetch the name of that cell item using "indexPath.row" and then check if that string or cell item's name exists in array[finalSelections], if it does fetch the index of that string or cell item's name using a pre defined function and then remove element at that index position ! After removing , reload the collection view as well so that cell will revert back to normal looking cell !

Answer (score 0):

Inside your collection view cell,

```
class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var serviceLbl: UILabel!
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
            else {
                contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then in controller declare,

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Finally, print index in didSelect

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems)
    }
```