# Swift make select/unselect in single/multiple selection mode for UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS and I want to implement a UICollectionView inside a UITableView which can have multiple select/unselect in section 1 of the UITableview. And in section 2, only a single selection is allowed. And save the selection sate event if I dismiss the Viewcontroller and when I open it again, it must show the last selected cell as highlight.

I searched for tutorials but all of them don't mention to select/unselect the state of collection cell or saving state after dismissing view controller.

Can someone help to implement it?

Thank in advance!

Here is my code I do till now:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return clvData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "clvCell", for: indexPath) as! demoCollectionViewCell
        cell.title.text = clvData[indexPath.item] as? String
        return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = .red
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

you guys can also check my project here:
https://mega.nz/#!xRs0EQyQ

Comment: could you please post here some code what you have done till now.

Comment: I added my code that I making the selection and upload my current demo project too. You can check it.

Comment: for multiple selection look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757524/how-do-i-got-multiple-selections-in-uicollection-view-using-swift-4).
and for single selection replace the array with a single object/data insteade of array.

Comment: So, how about the save selected state when dismissing view controller then opens again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this and let me know if you have any problem or if this solved your problem.

```
    var arrSelectedIndex:[IndexPath] = []// store this array either in database by api or in local
    var clvData:[String] = []// your data array

    //get the arrSelectedIndex from default in viewDidLoad before reloading the table and collection. 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let myArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedArray") as? [IndexPath] {
            arrSelectedIndex = myArray
        } else {
            arrSelectedIndex = []
        }
    }

    // and save the arrSelectedIndex in viewWillDisappear method
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(arrSelectedIndex, forKey: "selectedArray")
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return clvData.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "clvCell", for: indexPath) as! demoCollectionViewCell
            cell.title.text = clvData[indexPath.item] as? String

            if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) { // You need to check wether selected index array contain current index if yes then change the color
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }

            return cell

        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = .red
            if !arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {// if it does not contains the index then add it
                arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath)
            }
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = .white
            if let currIndex = arrSelectedIndex.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {// if it contains the index then delete from array
                arrSelectedIndex.remove(at: currIndex)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's work well. But one more requirement is to save the selected state of collection view after dismissing. And it's must highlight when reopening again. I'm currently using `UserDefaults` to save the `arrSelectedIndex` but it has a bug. You can check this gif for more details: https://media.giphy.com/media/S8B5Ajtg7zcYkvPsdg/giphy.gif

Comment: i am unable to see the gif, Can you write here what bugs you found? btw i have updated the answer, have a look on that.