# Stored selected indexPath of UICollectionView inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm currently making a screen that has an `UITableView` with many sections that have the content of cells is `UICollectionView`. Now I'm saving the selected indexPath of the collection into an array then save to `UserDefaults` (because the requirement is showing all cells has selected before when reopening view controller).

But I have the issues is when I reopen view controller all items in all sections with the same selected `indexPath` show the same state.

I know it occurs because I just save the only `indexPath` of the selected item without the `section` of `UITableview` which is holding the collection view. But I don't know how to check the sections. Can someone please help me to solve this problem? Thank in advance.

I'm following this solution [How do I got Multiple Selections in UICollection View using Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757524/how-do-i-got-multiple-selections-in-uicollection-view-using-swift-4)

And here is what I do in my code:

```
var usrDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    var encodedData: Data?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    if let act = usrDefault.data(forKey: "selected") {
        let outData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: act)
        arrSelectedIndex = outData as! [IndexPath]
    }else {
        arrSelectedData = []
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let optionItemCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "optionCell", for: indexPath) as! SDFilterCollectionCell
        let title = itemFilter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.item].option_name

    if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {
        optionItemCell.filterSelectionComponent?.bind(title: title!, style: .select)
        optionItemCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_red_50.rawValue)
        optionItemCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_red_300.rawValue).cgColor
    }else {
        optionItemCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_white.rawValue)
        optionItemCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_grey_100.rawValue).cgColor
        optionItemCell.filterSelectionComponent?.bind(title: title!, style: .unselect)
    }

    optionItemCell.layoutSubviews()

    return optionItemCell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let strData = itemFilter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.item]
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SDFilterCollectionCell

    cell?.filterSelectionComponent?.bind(title: strData.option_name!, style: .select)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_red_50.rawValue)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexaString: SDDSColor.color_red_300.rawValue).cgColor

    if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {
        arrSelectedIndex = arrSelectedIndex.filter{($0 != indexPath)}
        arrSelectedData = arrSelectedData.filter{($0 != strData)}
    }else {
        arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath)
        arrSelectedData.append(strData)

        encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arrSelectedIndex)
        usrDefault.set(encodedData, forKey: "selected")
    }

    if let delegate = delegate {
        if itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key.count > 0 {
            if (strData.option_id != "") {
                input.add(strData.option_id!)
                let output = input.componentsJoined(by: ",")
                data["search_key"] = itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key.count > 0 ?  itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key : strData.search_key;
                data["option_id"] = output
            }
        }else {
            data["search_key"] = itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key.count > 0 ?  itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key : strData.search_key;
            data["option_id"] = strData.option_id
        }

        delegate.filterTableCellDidSelectItem(item: data, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the collection view's in each table cell have multiple sections themselves or just one?  Also, does your table view use only sections or only rows to display the collection views, or do you have multiple sections each containing multiple rows?

Comment: My table view has 5 sections and each section contains only one cell and I display the collection in it. Collection view has just one section

Comment: Gotcha, then the answer I posted should work for your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work based on the assumption that both your parent table view and child collection views both are not using multiple sections with multiple rows and you only need to store one value for each to represent where an item is located in each respective view.

If I am understanding correctly, you have a collection view for each table view cell.  You are storing the selection of each collection view, but you need to also know the position of the collection view in the parent table?  A way to do this would be to add a property to your `UICollectionView` class or use the `tag` property and set it corresponding section it is positioned in the parent table.  Then when you save the selected `IndexPath`, you can set the `section` to be that collection view's property you created(or `tag` in the example) so that each selected `indexPath.section` represents the table view `section`, and the `indexPath.row` represents the collection view's row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
    let collectionView = UICollectionView()
    collectionView.tag = indexPath.section
    //...
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    indexPath.section = collectionView.tag
    let strData = itemFilter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.item]
    //...
```

}

Basically each selected index path you save will correspond to the following:

`indexPath.section` = table view section
`indexPath.row` = collection view row

`IndexPath(row: 5, section: 9)` would correlate to:
--table view cell at `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 9)` .
----collection view cell at `IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)`

Edit:  This is how you can use the saved index paths in your current code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //...
    let tempIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: collectionView.tag)
    if arrSelectedIndex.contains(tempIndexPath) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
    //...
```

}

Comment: `indexPath.section = collectionView.tag` this will make an error: `Cannot assign to property: 'indexPath' is a 'let' constant`. And with your solution do I need to add the only indexPath like what I've done then it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath)` in the `cellForItemAt` method is not correct.

Each time a UICollectionView in a `UITableView`'s section is loaded, this will called the `cellForItemAt` for ALL cells.

Here is the error :

In your GIF example the first cell is selected in the first collectionView, you will store (0, 0) in the array.

But when the second collectionView will loads its cells, it will check if the indexPath (0, 0) is contained into your array. It is the case, so the backgroundColor will be selected.

This error will be reproduced on every collectionView stored in your tableView sections.

You should probably also store the sectionIndex of your `UITableView` into your array of `IndexPath`.

Comment: Can you please make some cleary code? I know where I'm wrong but I don't know how to store the section index then compare it with the selected index of the collection view. Sorry because of I'm new in iOS